# cannot access 'rootfs' on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu

I'm trying to update my `.bash_profile` on Ubuntu on Windows and I'm not able to enter 'rootfs' directory. 
`ls -l` outputs

```
d--------- 1 me me 4096 Jul 22 09:17 rootfs
```

And chmod or sudo chmod still errors with:

```
chmod: cannot read directory 'rootfs/': Permission denied
```

What should I do, check?

Comment: So are you a normal user or are you using Root?  If you are not using Root, switch to Root, and try accessing the directory.  But you don’t have permissions on that directory, in fact nobody does, so you will have to chmod on it.

Comment: The user you are using is the owner, and the group that user is in owns the file, but neither of permissions to the file.  Additionally, any other user, doesn’t have access. My suggestion is to completely Reset your WSL instance because something doesn’t seem right.  If I was provided more information I could formulate an answer though

Comment: @Ramhound - I tried sudo, I can see th # in the command line but still chmod doesn't seem to be working. I'll try to reinstall ubuntu on windows and see if that helps. What info would you need?

Comment: What (where) is this `rootfs` and why are you trying to access it?

Answer (score 2):

the linux root filesystem of WSL is a directory at C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4\LocalState\rootfs\

Similarly, the windows filesystem is accessible in the linux subsystem as mounted block devices at /mnt/c, /mnt/d, ..., which correspond to the windows C:\ drive, D:\, etc.

Since both the WSL filesystem and the windows filesystem have a link to each other, this could potentially create an infinitely looping directory path, 
You can imagine something like this:

```
/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Packages/TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4/LocalState/rootfs/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Packages/TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4....
```

or

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4\LocalState\rootfs\mnt\c\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4\LocalState\rootfs\mnt\c...
```

But this is not possible. The filesystem bridges/interfaces only work one level deep.

If you navigate with windows explorer to 
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4\LocalState\rootfs\mnt\c you might expect to find the same files as in C:\ but it is empty because this mounted C: drive directory only works inside WSL.

Similarly, if you are in WSL and navigate to /mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Packages/TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4/LocalState, you will see that there is a directory called rootfs. This directory's permission/mode can't be changed, not even by root, because it is a special interface file that only has meaning outside of WSL, for windows explorer.

So to answer the question, if you are using WSL and want to modify linux configuration files like .bash_profile, you shouldn't try to navigate into the windows explorer directory that bridges the linux rootfs to windows explorer, but instead you should directly edit the files under /, which in this case is /home/$USERNAME/bash_profile

Comment: In this location, all I can find is an ext4 VHD !! Is this the rootfs ? How do I access it ? I cant mount it. And if I do it kinda breaks my WSL2 !! "This file is being accessed by another program" msg flashes when I try to run ubuntu after trying to mount the ext4. How do I get to my rootfs ?